# Should primary key in all table set as foreign key in other table?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, erd

I am doing my database assignment with the business system, airline reservation system.

And I found that all primary keys in my ERD table are a foreign key in other tables except the `psg_seat_no` in `ticket_detail` table. Is that normal?

Here is my ERD:

[image]

Comment: Probably not. If this is data that is entered and is not stored in another table it should not have a foreign key

Comment: That is normal.  A primary key does not have to be a foreign key.

Comment: Ok, I see now, thank you.

Comment: If the correctness is important you should probably check whether it is in a normal form or not.

Comment: Btw, `transactions.tr_id` is also not referenced. Of course there are PKs which are never referenced, otherwise your data model would never stop growing :_)

Answer (score 0):

Your ER diagram is in 3 NF architecture so its always better to define a primary key as foreign key.
This reduces duplication of data in both tables whether u r directly accessing the larger table or indirectly by accessing small table.

Comment: That wasn't his question.